# Using xpath3 in dwl-Transform Message

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I want check if a Node is present in an XML payload or not. For this purpose I want to use xpath3() in Transform Message in mule4.

Input:

```
<XML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ABC xsi:nil="true"/>
    <DEF/>
</XML>
```

dataweave code:

```
%dw2.0
output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
---
if(xpath3('//:ABC',payload.XML,'BOOLEAN')
 "abc": "yes
else
 "abc": "no"
```

Expected Output(
json):

```
{
"abc": "yes"
}
```

Please Help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason why use xpath? You could achieve the same result using the following dataweave expressions:

1. Check if element exists (whether it's nil or not)

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
---
{
    "abc": if (payload.XML.ABC?) "yes" else "no"
}
```

2. Check if element is present and not nil (nil must be set to false or removed when ABC has a value):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
---
{
    "abc": if (!isEmpty(payload.XML.ABC)) "yes" else "no"
}
```

Example of output using these expressions:

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks for the response olamiral, but the logic which you suggested, in both cases the output will be "no" . xsi:nil="true" indicates that the element is null and I have to use skipNullOn to eliminate other null elements, I am using Xpath so that even if the <ABC> has xsi:nil="true" I should be able to detect its existence in the payload.

Comment: That's strange: I used the payload you provided and run some tests where it returns the expected value (in the 1st case, if ABC exists (with xsi:nil true or false), the expression returns 'yes' else 'no'. In the 2nd case, the expression returns 'no' when ABC does not exist or its value is empty or its value is not empty but xsi:nil is true. Otherwise, it returns 'yes'. Could you give additional information on how you are running the tests?

Comment: Regarding skipNullOn, it affects the output and has nothing to do with the XML provided as an input. This property will remove from the output all JSON properties having a null value.

Comment: Added a screenshot to illustrate the expression behaviors.

Comment: Hey Olamiral, I have a json now { "abc" : "" } I want to convert this to xml as <abc xsi:nil="true">. The reverse of this process, How do I do that?

Comment: Hey Amer, it is recommended to ask it in a new question, as it’s a different issue. That way, it can help others that may have a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

DataWeave 2.x (in Mule 4.x) does not have an xpath3() function. If for some reason you want to use XPATH inside DataWeave you will have to develop the function yourself, though I would advise against doing it.

The recommended way is to migrate it to a DataWeave expression, like @olamiral solution.